# Verify if a hard drive is encrypted on Linux

Tags: linux, fedora, encryption

How can I verify if a hard drive is encrypted in Fedora 20?

If not, does it mean I have to re install Fedora to encrypt it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Assuming that the drive is `/dev/sdb`, and the partition you want to check is `/dev/sdb1`, run this command:

```
$ blkid /dev/sdb1
```

the output will change if the partition is encrypted or not:

```
/dev/sdb1: UUID="xxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"   #encrypted
/dev/sdb1: UUID="xxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="ext4"          #not encrypted, fs is ext4
```

If the partition is not encrypted, and assuming that you are NOT trying to encrypt the `/` partition, you have to:

- Make a backup of the data on that partition
- Initialize the partition as encrypted

  ```
  $ cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdb1
  ```

**BEWARE: this command will wipe all the contents of the partition!!!** 
It will ask you for a passphrase to open the volume; now if you try to run `blkid`, the output should be `TYPE="crypto_LUKS"`

- Open the encrypted partition to use it

  ```
  $ cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 secret
  ```

where "`secret`" is the name of the volume we are opening

- Format the new "`secret`" volume

  ```
  $ mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/secret
  ```
- Mount it providing the passphrase created before

  ```
  $ mount /dev/mapper/secret /whereyouwant
  ```

  Now you should be able to use the encrypted partition!

Optionally, if you want to mount it at reboot, you should edit `/etc/crypttab` and insert a line similar to this (**it will request the password at boot**):

```
secret /dev/sdb1 none
```

Where `secret` is the name of the volume we created before.

Or something like this, if you want to put your password in some plain text file:

```
secret /dev/sdb1 /whereyouwant-sdb1-luks-pwdfile
```

Just keep in mind for this, you also have to add the key:

```
$ cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sdb1 /whereyouwant-sdb1-luks-pwdfile
```

And edit the `/etc/fstab` and insert a line similar to this:

```
/dev/mapper/secret /whereyouwant ext4 defaults 1 2
```

Comment: many thanks, but what should I do if I need the whole disk be encrypted.

Comment: Just repeat the `blkid /dev/sdbx` command for each partition.

Comment: it's obvious =), I mean what to do if I need to encrypt the whole disk. To reinstall Fedora and chose encrypted LVM during installation will be the only option?

Comment: Sorry, my bad :) Yes, the only option is to reinstall Fedora, sadly.

Comment: yeah, sadly. Many thanks for the information, ludiegu.

Comment: On Ubuntu, I didn't realize this command would show no output with exit status zero. Run as superuser for output `sudo blkid /dev/sdb1`

Comment: What if I want to know, programmatically, if the lvm logical volume mounted on / is on an encrypted partition?

Comment: Is there a way to check this without assumption a disk? Then this defeat the purpose of verifying thing automatically. For example I want a bash script to tell me whether the current OS is encrypted with LUKS (full disk encryption) without giving clue which disk. Asking this based on the exact question what OP is asking but most of your answers here are not related to the title of the question.

Comment: What if `blkid` does not return any information?

Comment: Then try `sudo blkid`